# How is it possible to get Windows default user profile path via CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Windows default user profile is usually `%SystemDrive%\users\default` but its real location is not an environment variable but it can be useful to have it.
Default user profile path can be detected by system registry query like that

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /v "Default"') do set "defaultuserprofile=%%b"
echo %defaultuserprofile%
pause
```

But we get the value `%SystemDrive%\Users\Default` where `%SystemDrive%` is not converted to `C:` (*or other letter*) so environment variable `%defaultuserprofile%` can not be used as normal environment variable path for file operations.
Alternative variant can be something like

```
@echo off
cd /d "%public%"
cd ..\
set usersdir=%cd%
set defaultuserprofile=%usersdir%\default
echo %defaultuserprofile%
pause
```

But it seems to be not so good.
So how is it possible to get Windows default user profile path via CMD?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Windows 10 doesn't have a `default` user.

Comment: What are you really trying to do that requires access to this folder path?  It's sort of unusual to run a script like this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't your really want `%PUBLIC%`, which is `C:\Users\Public`?  At least that's closest equivalent on Windows 10 to a "Default" folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "defaultuserprofile="

for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /v "Default"') do (
    if "%%~A" == "Default" call set "defaultuserprofile=%%C"
)

echo "%defaultuserprofile%"
pause
```

The type of the data is `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. To expand the `%SystemDrive%` embedded in the string, use `call set`. `call` causes another parse of the command so that `set` assigns `C:\` instead of `%SystemDrive%`.

Like the 2nd OP code, which is not as reliable as the reg query:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%Public%\..\Default" || exit /b 1
echo "%cd%"
pause
```

If you want to view the `Default` folder and other hidden folders in the Users directory, use:

```
dir /a:h
```

Output is the symlink named `All Users`, the folder named `Default` and the symlink named `Default User` on Windows 10 v1903.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, just to mention the purpose of the Default user profile is as the basis for all new user profiles. Therefore it should be used only to configure applications, settings and customizations for each future new user account on the PC. *(modifications within it do not propagate to existing users).*

The following method is similar to the existing answer, in that an additional expansion is used to cater for any variables within the contained data string. *Please note that the value type of the data is by default REG_EXPAND_SZ, but it can also be of type REG_SZ, (the expand type is only necessary if the string contains a variable).*

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set "RKey=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
Set "RVal=Default"
Set "ProfilePath="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%G In (
    '""%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" Query "%RKey%" /V "%RVal%" 2>NUL|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" /I "%RVal%""'
)Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ('Echo("%%~H"')Do Set "ProfilePath=%%~I"
If Not Defined ProfilePath Exit /B 1
Rem Your code using "%ProfilePath%" goes below here
Echo "%ProfilePath%" & Pause
```

I have `Rem`arked a line with comment, *which can be optionally omitted*, and provided an example line below it for demonstration purposes, *please modify that as necessary*.

The code uses full paths for all external commands, (via a special variable, `%__APPDIR__%`, *which will always point to their correct location*). I have done that in order to remove any reliance on the content of the editable environment variables `%PATH%` and `%PATHEXT%`, *(deliberate, or accidental, modification of those two environment variables could otherwise break the code)*.